# Error using paho-mqtt in App Engine Python App

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mqtt, google-cloud-platform, paho

I am trying to right a Google Cloud Platform app in python with Flask that makes an MQTT connection. I have included the paho python library by doing `pip install paho-mqtt -t libs/`. However, when I try to run the app, even if I don't try to connect to MQTT. I get a weird error about IP address checking:
`RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)`

It seems something in the `remote_socket` lib is causing a problem. Is this a security issue? Is there someway to disable it?

Relevant code:

```
from flask import Flask
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import logging as logger


app = Flask(__name__)


# Note: We don't need to call run() since our application is embedded within
# the App Engine WSGI application server.

#callback to print out connection status
def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
    logger.info('on_connect')
    if rc == 0:
        logger.info("Connected")
        mqttc.subscribe('test', 0)
    else:
        logger.info(rc)

def on_message(mqttc, obj, msg):
    logger.info(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.qos)+" "+str(msg.payload))

mqttc = mqtt.Client("mqttpy")
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
```

As well as full stack trace:

```
ERROR    2014-06-03 15:14:57,285 wsgi.py:262]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/cbarnes/code/ignite/tank-demo/appengine-flask-demo/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    mqttc = mqtt.Client("mqtthtpp")
  File "/Users/cbarnes/code/ignite/tank-demo/appengine-flask-demo/lib/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 403, in __init__
    self._sockpairR, self._sockpairW = _socketpair_compat()
  File "/Users/cbarnes/code/ignite/tank-demo/appengine-flask-demo/lib/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 255, in _socketpair_compat
    listensock.bind(("localhost", 0))
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/socket.py", line 222, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 668, in bind
    self._SetProtoFromAddr(request.mutable_proxy_external_ip(), address)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 632, in _SetProtoFromAddr
    proto.set_packed_address(self._GetPackedAddr(address))
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 627, in _GetPackedAddr
    AI_NUMERICSERV|AI_PASSIVE):
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 338, in getaddrinfo
    canonical=(flags & AI_CANONNAME))
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 211, in _Resolve
    canon, aliases, addresses = _ResolveName(name, families)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 229, in _ResolveName
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('remote_socket', 'Resolve', request, reply)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 328, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Users/cbarnes/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 234, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise pickle.loads(response_pb.exception())
RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)
INFO     2014-06-03 15:14:57,291 module.py:639] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did this finally work for you? I think GAE started to allow socket connections.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to connect to host `test` and port `0` where typically you should use `localhost` and `1883`

See the getting started example here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/0.9#usage-and-api